# Jump to next section in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, anchor, advanced-custom-fields

OK, this is a bit complicated so Ill try my best to explain it:

I have a while loop which has a next link, before I just had it in standard html, so it was farely simple, on click of the class 'arrow' it would just to the next section e.g:

```
    $i = 0;

    while ( have_rows('sections') ) : the_row();
    $sectionName = $i++;
    ?>
        <section id="<?php echo $sectionName; ?>" class="full-bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php the_sub_field('section_image'); ?>')">
            <div class="image divider" id="partnersImg" style="background-image: url('<?php the_sub_field('section_image'); ?>')">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="overlay" style="color: <?php the_field('section_text_colour','options'); ?>">
                        <?php the_sub_field('divider_text'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sectionContent">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="centerContent">
                        <div class="contentWrapper">

                            <div class="text animation-element" data-sr="enter center wait 0.5s, no reset" style="background-color: <?php the_field('text_block_bg_colour','options'); ?>; color: <?php the_field('text_block_text_colour','options'); ?>">
                                <?php the_sub_field('section_text'); ?>
                                <div class="arrowContainer"><a href="<?php echo "#".$sectionName; ?>" class="arrow next"></a></div> 
                            </div>


                            <div class="clr"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

    <?php endwhile;
```

The sectionName variable is set for each item name that is added in the wordpress admin however the issue comes when my above code shows and the anchor is linking too itself and not the next section, I would like to know how to link it to the next section and if its the last section then to have a anchor which links to the first.

```
<section id="0">
<div class="arrowContainer"><a href="#0" class="arrow next"></a></div> 
</section>

<section id="1">
<div class="arrowContainer"><a href="#1" class="arrow next"></a></div> 
</section>

<section id="2">
<div class="arrowContainer"><a href="#2" class="arrow next"></a></div> 
</section>

<section id="3">
<div class="arrowContainer"><a href="#3" class="arrow back"></a></div> 
</section>
```

In this case I am using Advanced Custom Fields repeater and not posts.

Comment: Do you have the HTML sample ? And what code did work (when you say "so it **was** farely simple" ?

Comment: Tip: Try to use 1 word class names only. In your css it might get f*cked up when you use spaces..

Comment: You may collect all your post objects in array, and then using `for` loop - output your post and get slug to next one. In the end there would be condition, to the first post. If it's complicated, will try to type some code)
Also there is WP function [get_next_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)

Comment: I have changed the anchor to be an ID but I still face the same issue the a href attached to the arrow class, I now need to increment the $sectionName in the while loop by 1 but I don't know how?